How does the steering wheel return to the centre after turning (and letting go)? What forces are causing the self centreing torque?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLbs8kBXgrw
I watched this video (please watch it for context as I am following the same scenario). Despite the nice animations I am still confused.
I tried to visualise and imagine it, then I sketched it, but I still don't understand what forces are at play to cause the self centering torque, that causes the wheel to go from tilted to straight.
Here is my interpretation. The scenario is a left turn. First I drew the scenario:

blue dotted line is the steering axis to which the wheel pivots, caused by the result of a positive caster angle
The red dash is where the tyre contacts the road. T
the purple arrow is the centripetal force pointing inward
The wheel is turning left, and the direction of the turn is left
Then I drew a top down view of above diagram (excuse the poor diagram): -blue line is the steering axis, dotted line is how it orients itself after centering. -purple arrow is the centripetal force that causes an inwards torque at the pivot -red arrow is the self centering torque

This is the top view of the forces/torques
(P.S. just realised that the pivot is actually "imaginary", all the forces and torques acting are through the contact point of the tyre on road. I don't think that invalidates the logic but yes the diagram of torques acting is certainly not right)
I don't see what force is acting in the right/opposite direction to the centripetal force, therefore I don't understand how the self centering torque will rotate the wheel right. Obviously it must rotate right to straighten the wheel and centre. However the only force in the video mentioned is the centripetal force, which is inward, and causes a leftward torque at the pivot towards the centre of the turn.
is it friction? Can someone give me a diagram of the moment arm and the forces?
Thanks

So inspect a simple example like a shopping cart, look at the "steering" wheels.

To add to Dave Tweed's answer: Note that the castering geometry which acts to recenter the steering when coming out of a turn is completely reversed when the car is backing up. In this case, the car's steering geometry acts to push the car into a full-deflection turn (this is called yaw divergence) and if uncorrected the car will then drive itself backwards around and around in a tight circle.
People got killed this way, as follows: In the 1960's, cars made by Ford had a flaw in the shift mechanism of their automatic transmissions which would occasionally cause the car to "jump" by itself out of the park detent position and into the reverse detent position with the engine running. So let's say the driver stops at the mailbox to pick up the day's mail and puts the car in park with the engine running. They then get out of the car and while getting the mail, the car hops out of park and into reverse and takes off without the driver! The backwards-castering then forces the front wheels into a full-lock turn and the car then comes around through a full circle and strikes and runs over the driver.
Ford fixed the flaw and now their cars do not jump into reverse on their own.

The caster angle means that when the wheel is turned, the contact patch moves left/right with respect to where the steering axis intersects the ground (the "pivot point"). This means that the forces on the contact patch now have a left/right component that is directed back to the neutral steering position.

When the wheel is turned so that the plane of rotation no longer aligns with the vehicle's momentum, a centripetal force is produced that is at right angles to the lever arm that connects the center of the contact patch to the pivot point.

I see. So the contact patch is where the force is applied , which causes a torque due to the pivot being in front of the contact patch?

Could you give me a diagram if possible? thanks

The steering axis of the wheel is both inclined by 3-10 degrees, giving castor, and offset longitudinally, striking the ground somewhat ahead of the nominal centre of the contact patch, this distance is called the mechanical trail, typically about 25 mm. The lateral force generated at the contact patch has a centroid somewhat behind the nominal centre of the CP. This distance is called the pneumatic trail, typically about 30mm at medium cornering loads. As the tire lateral force peaks this drops to zero which is why the steering goes light at max latacc.
So the lateral force at the CP causes a torque around the steering axis of Fy*(mech trail+pneu trail)*cos(castor). This torque acts to straighten the wheel.
Sometimes people get this wrong - the first generation X5 would go to full lock when parking if you let go of the steering wheel.
There are other effects that help with centring but that's the big one.
An alternative would be to use the power steering to return the wheel to centre - Citroen and some tractors did this at the cost of removing all steering feel.
